# Where to put controller code for Yii2 sidebar modal form?

Tags: forms, controller, modal-dialog, yii2

I want to have a modal **Report Issue** form in the sidebar that loads on every page.  I can't seem to wrap my head around where to place the `controller/form` initialization code.

A typical controller action:

```
public function actionContact()
{
    $model = new Feedback();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->sendEmail()) {
        Yii::$app->getSession()->addFlash('success', 'Thank you for contacting us.<br /><br />We will respond as soon as possible.');
        $model = new Feedback();
    }
    if (Yii::$app->request->isPjax) {
        return $this->renderAjax('contact', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('contact', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The `$model` is set when the action is first called, but if the modal is to be placed in the sidebar, every controller and/or `controller/action` could be called, and I don't want to have the `$model` initialization repeated each time (DRY).

I'm not sure if this is a prime condition for a custom `widget`, or a `controller->beforeAction`, or something else altogether.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a widget. The widget will create an empty $model and pass it to it's view. You can insert the widget in any view or in the layout too.

Regarding the

> every controller and/or controller/action could be called

why would any controller be called? Your form should send the info to 1 controller/action not any of them. The widget will be shown by any controller/action but the widget's form will always just call 1.

Comment: A widget is what I thought I needed.  What should the form action be?  Should I create a `WidgetController` and have an action for each form widget?  I'm not sure how to send processed data back to the widget after submission, for instance a `flash` message from a validation error.

Comment: I was able to get it working right.  I did create a `WidgetController` and modified the form action to call the `WidgetController->action`.  This way, the widget can be called from the sidebar which is located on every page.  I do use Pjax so the `WidgetController` just returns the widget instance again and the page isn't refreshed.  I am not sure how my setup would run without using Pjax.

Comment: Pjax is still just Ajax. So you can just use AJAX directly. The difference is that with PJAX the entire page is re-rendered usually and only the pjax container is updated, with Ajax nothing stops you from just returning the widget again so only that part will be rendered. I would leave it like it is and revisit the issue when time permits. Unless you have a really visited website these kinds of improvements are not really necessary.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Thank you.